# Basic Crypto for .NET

Tags: c#, cryptography

Please tell me if I'm doing this right, and what else is needed to make this hardened.

It seems like it's too simple, like there's almost nothing I'm actually doing.  For example, there are 4 or 5 stacked using statements!

Here is the code to review:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var enc = true;
        var fileIn = string.Empty;
        var fileOut = string.Empty;

        /* parse command line to populate enc, fileIn, fileOut */

        Console.Write("key: ");
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("IV: ");
        var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());

        using (var aes = AesManaged.Create())
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        using (var readStream = File.OpenRead(fileIn))
        using (var writeStream = File.OpenWrite(fileOut))
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
            enc ? writeStream : readStream, 
            enc 
                ? aes.CreateEncryptor(md5.ComputeHash(key), md5.ComputeHash(iv))
                : aes.CreateDecryptor(md5.ComputeHash(key), md5.ComputeHash(iv)),
            enc ? CryptoStreamMode.Write : CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            if (enc) { readStream.CopyToAsync(cryptoStream).Wait(); }
            else { cryptoStream.CopyToAsync(writeStream).Wait(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CreateEncryptor()` and `CreateDecryptor` both return an `IDisposable` object which should be wrapped in a `using` clause before it's passed to the `CryptoStream`.

Comment: I think to get the best value out of reviews/answers, you should *definitely* include the `/* parse command line to populate enc, fileIn, fileOut */` commented-out part.

Comment: @jesse good catch!

Comment: In what context will this program be used? Why do you hash the given key and IV, instead of giving the user full control over the input? Also, there are known attacks against MD5. I don't know how that affects your use of it here, but I'd use a more secure algorithm just to be sure.

Comment: @mat's mug I can't! The app wouldn't let me submit it with that code.

Comment: Pieter Witvoet Great catch, I'm using only to achieve the correct number of bytes. I guess paying would work, but I'm not sure what is standard...

Comment: Try from a desktop, I doubt it makes the post surpass the 65K character limit ;-)

Comment: Still, in what context will this program be used? Against what must it be hardened? Anyway, I think it's better to ask this question over at https://security.stackexchange.com - misusing cryptographic primitives often doesn't produce obviously wrong results. Most programmers won't be able to detect flaws in cryptographic code because they don't have the required theoretical background and mindset. I know I don't.

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert in cryptography by any stretch of the imagination but I am pretty sure an IV should be randomly generated.

> " In cryptography, an initialization vector (IV) or starting variable (SV)[1] is a fixed-size input to a cryptographic primitive that is typically required to be random or pseudorandom. Randomization is crucial for encryption schemes to achieve semantic security [...] " -
>
> <sub>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector</sub>

Answer (score 2):

IV it's intended to be quite long and variant, so yep inserting it manually is not a problem but if take an high entropy long string is better.

MD5: it's the weakest hash possible, consider to use SHA-*